# How can I get current scroll position on UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, webview

I have a UIWebView And how can i get It's scroll position ?

I know, that UIWebView has a UIScroller subview. But I can't get offset of this UIScroller (((

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This trick works for me.

```
UIWebView *webView;
int scrollPosition = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];
```

Please refer to the answer given by zamber for a better solution on iOS 5 and later. My answer was for iOS 4 and below.

Comment: Thanks. Super. It's works

May be you know, how can I get WebView content size, with javaScript? (window.innerHeight doesn't work)

Comment: You can get the height and width from javascript. See this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230660/can-width-height-of-a-powerpoint-presentation-be-calculated-on-ipad

Comment: This answer was appropriate for iOS 4. From iOS 5 and later,  you should use the scrollView property, as zamber answered.

Answer (score 15):

There is a better and more resource-friendly way to do this:

```
UIWebView *webView;
CGFloat offset = webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

via http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html